# How to keep feature ID within GeoJSON ogr2ogr import to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geojson, ogr2ogr

I'm attempting to import a GeoJSON file into PostGIS using ogr2ogr

The basic command is

`ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=my_db user=postgres" my_file.geojson -preserve_fid -nln geo_table -append`

Using this sample how do I rewrite it so the id becomes a id Colum in the database table?

`{"type":"Polygon","id":123,"coordinates":[[[100,0],[101,0],[101,1],[100,1],[100,0]]]}`

Produces

`ERROR 1: ERROR:  setval: value 0 is out of bounds for sequence`

The "real" file contains both Polygon & MultiPolygon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the GeoJSON specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946:

> If a Feature has a commonly used identifier, that identifier SHOULD be
> included as a member of the Feature object with the name "id", and the
> value of this member is either a JSON string or number.

Your GeoJSON has id at wrong level as a member of Polygon object. Move it higher.

```
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 123, "properties": {"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[100,0],[101,0],[101,1],[100,1],[100,0]]]}}}
```